# How do I use multithreading to control a surfaceview in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I'm creating an android game (still a begginer at android development, so be kind), and I will have several objects moving around on screen.

I'm using a thread and surfaceview to control all images on screen.

Each object will have its on speed so I wonder how this can be done. I though in using multiple threads, each object with its own thread and then it would be drawn to the surfaceview... how can I use the same surfaceview since it is on a different class?

If you don't understand what I mean, please tell me and I'll explain in another way.

Thanks.

Comment: Use this game engine and forget about threading :- http://www.andengine.org/

Comment: I already know about that engine but I would want to develop this game without the help of any engine ;)

Comment: I've already managed to create multiple threads when I want, but I don't know how to order them to draw inside my surfaceview... I create a thread everytime I click on the screen.

Comment: see Threads pools with the Executor Framework  here :-http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Comment: Thanks but I've already managed to do this by myself :) It's not that hard... I simply create a class extended from SurfaceView and inside this class I create an instance from a class which implements a runnable and this class receives the SurfaceView holder and inside its "run" method, I draw all I want :) Thanks for your help and I hope to help other people with this same doubt.